# Groovy method as variable

Tags: groovy

I have the following Groovy script:

```
def Deploy() {
  if (App == "TEST"){
      def book = load "book.groovy"
      book.buildList.each {
          a lot of actions
      }
  else {
     book.each {
          the same a lot of actions
     }
}
```

So the difference only in execution methods (properties): book.buildList.each or book.each. How to avoid to repeat those a lot of actions and keep code cleaner. Probably there is a way to put `book.buildList.each` or `book.each` into the variable?
File Book.groovy contain few map:

```
buildList = [
  'key1':'value1',
  'key2':'value2',
  'key3':'value3',
]   
anotherList = [
  'key11':'value11',
  'key22':'value22',
  'key33':'value33',
] 
return this
```

But if `App not "TEST"` I have `book` map:

```
[
  'key1':'value1',
  'key2':'value2',
  'key3':'value3',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If both `each` invocations do the exact same thing, you can extract the body of the closure you pass to `each` method to a variable and share it between both invocations. Consider the following (simplified) example:

```groovy
def closure = { k, v ->
    println "k = $k, v = $v"
}

def a = [
        'key1': 'value1',
        'key2': 'value2',
        'key3': 'value3',
]

def b = [
        'key11': 'value11',
        'key22': 'value22',
        'key33': 'value33',
]

println "Calling common closure on the map a:"
a.each closure

println "Calling common closure on the map b:"
b.each closure
```

In this example, I common closure to the variable, and then I was able to re-use it in both iterations. Also, keep in mind that in your example you are using maps, not lists. Calling `each` on map is absolutely correct, and in this case, you can use a closure with `k` and `v` parameters to map key and value accurately.